# my desktop is 16 hours continuously running Would it be ok to do this?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer, desktop-customization

My work is done from home. For which I have to keep my desktop running for 16 hours. Will there be any problem with my desktop by doing this? I just got a new system

Comment: Do you have reason to believe things will not be ok leaving your computer on that long?

Answer (score 5):

I've had computers here running for 10 years without ever sleeping, rebooting only for OS updates.
I doubt overnight is going to be any issue.

Comment: At one job, there was an ancient Dell desktop running for 15 years straight and ran for a few more years till the company was shutdown

Answer (score 0):

A modern computer can run 24x7 for years on end with no issues. Restarts for maintenance and updates is all that is required.

There is certainly no issue with leaving the computer on for 16 hours a day.

With an SSD and an energy saving monitor, my computers draw about 10 watts of power and so even power draw is not excessive.

Leave your computer ON and set your monitor to go black when not in use.